Powershell alias, parameterized function
I have an app executable say.exe to talk the string in specified language. Some of the commands I run repetedly:
> c:\say.exe --voice 11 "that's wicked, innit" # say sentence out loud in English.
> c:\say.exe --voice 7 "Mamma, voglio la pasta." # say sentence out loud in Italian
...

I'd like to have aliases that would spare me from specifying the --voice X parameter and putting the sentence in quotes
> say_en that''s wicked, innit.
> say_it Mamma, voglio la pasta.
...

Attempt
Set-Alias -Name say_en -Value "c:\say.exe --voice 11"
Creation successful. Fails when running

The term 'c:\say.exe --voice 11' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,...

Oh, you need to create a function
Function sayWithVoice7 {
    C:\say.exe --voice 7 "$args"
}
Set-Alias -Name say_it -Value sayWithVoice7

Function sayWithVoice14 {
    C:\say.exe --voice 14 "$args"
}
Set-Alias -Name say_en -Value sayWithVoice14
...

but now I have say N function for N aliases.
I'd like to have a parameterized function
Function sayWithVoice {
    Param ($voice_id)
    C:\say.exe --voice $voice_id "$args"
}
Set-Alias -Name say_en -Value sayWithVoice 11 # wrong way to pass 11
Set-Alias -Name say_it -Value sayWithVoice 7 # wrong way to pass 7
....

but it doesn't allow me to pass a parameter to sayWithVoice from within the alias definition. Tried sayWithVoice(11), doesn't work.
How do I pass the argument 11 to sayWithVoice?

Note to self: In powershell, use aliases only for dumb things, functions for everything else. Properly named functions serve very well as aliases. That is, int the question example the alias-functions pairs were overkill, the functions were enough

Indeed: PowerShell aliases are merely alternative names (typically short ones) for commands, i.e they can only map a name to another command name or executable file path; unlike in, say, Bash, defining arguments as part of the mapping is not supported; for the latter, you need a function - see this answer for details. GitHub issue #12962 is a proposal to someday support Bash-style aliases in PowerShell too.

@mklement0 thanks for the references. You have a great style explaining. Had I gotten to the items you'd written I wouldn't have needed to ask here. (I need a better search engine)

Glad to hear my comment helped, @parml. It's not always easy to find the right information.

You could use a hashtable to map country codes to voice identifiers, then create the wrapper functions programmatically by writing to the function: drive:
$voiceMap = @{
  en = 11
  it = 7
  # ... and so on
}

foreach ($pair in $voiceMap.GetEnumerator()) {
  Set-Content -Path "function:\say_$($pair.Name)" -Value "& say.exe --voice $($pair.Value) ""`$args"""
}

You'll now have two functions defined: say_en and say_it
